# LaTeX suddenly not working

Tags: errors, python

I'm submitting my Ph.D. thesis in 2 days - everything has been working fine for the last 3 years...now I get this:

```
Typesetting “Montgomery_MM_India_v21.tex”…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/site.py", line 73, in __boot()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/site.py", line 2, in __boot
    import sys, imp, os, os.path
  ImportError: No module named os 

Theme:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/site.py", line 73, in __boot()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/../../Extras/lib/python/site.py", line 2, in __boot
    import sys, imp, os, os.path
  ImportError: No module named os
```

I am using TextMate to compile a PDF - I'm not computer savvy but have been using LaTeX for awhile, I'm on a Mac with OS 10.7. Also of interest is when trying to compile - something called `SLFSharedPrefTools` starts using 100% of my CPU.

Pointing me in direction to help solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One great thing about latex - zip all of your files up, find a friend with a working installation and get them to compile for you.

Comment: What's the command you run that suddenly generates these error messages? Are these errors related to `python` or to `(La)TeX`?

Comment: @Mico These are most certainly python errors, probably to do with OP's *interface* to LaTeX.  TeX has *zero* dependence on Python, unless they are using an as yet unbeknownst to me implementation of TeX.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with your Python instalation:

```
No module named os
```

Module `os` is a very standard part of the package. Maybe reinstall Python and/or TextMate?

Also, you can probably compile your thesis from console (however it is called on Macs), and postpone resolving the above problem until after you turn your thesis in.

Comment: You can reach the console by typing 'Terminal' into spotlight and then following any decent set of compilation instructions (usually only three or four two-word commands).  (Perhaps this would be good to link out to?)